# Divide N rows to N columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result set which provide me 2 columns named `Sequence` and `CorrectAns` and it contains N rows(100 rows right now to be specific).

Now what I want is to divide these 100 rows to N columns(right now into 4 columns).

So, how to do that? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

This is the result that i am getting. Now what I want is something like this:

Seq ColA Seq ColB Seq ColC Seq ColD
1     C       4       A       7       C       10       D
2       A       5       C       8       A       11       C
3       A       6       A       9       C       12       A

and so on.

Hope this helps

Comment: Kindly provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Pivot is what you are looking for

Comment: added example of what I needed

Comment: Please provide your current sql

Comment: Its Simply Select Query.<br>Select Sequence, CorrectAns,NTILE(4) over(order by Sequence) as 'gro' From [Table]

Comment: @sagi yes I too think I need pivot syntax to achieve this. But I never tried that before I searched over the net and tried to use it but I failed.

Comment: just posted the syntax you want for pivot, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to pivot your data. Aside from the `PIVOT` command, one way to do that is to use conditional aggregation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce882/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Seq) -1) % 
                (SELECT CEILING(COUNT(*) / (4 * 1.0)) FROM tbl)
    FROM tbl
),
CteFinal AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY Seq)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    SeqA = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Seq END),
    ColA = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CorrectAns END),
    SeqB = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Seq END),
    ColB = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CorrectAns END),
    SeqC = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Seq END),
    ColC = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN CorrectAns END),
    SeqD = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Seq END),
    ColD = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN CorrectAns END)
FROM CteFinal
GROUP BY grp
```

Comment: Thanks it's this what I need. Now the only thing  I wanna ask can it be dynamic? means firstly removal of those last 2 columns in the SeqD and ColD? and secondly how to dynamically add more sequence and columns? can it be possible.

Answer (score 1):

use the following query,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Seq, CorrectAns, 
        gro
    FROM your_table
) as t
PIVOT
(
    SUM(gro)
    FOR CorrectAns IN (A,B,C,D....)
)AS pvt
```

Comment: It is showing me 1,2,3,4 in the columns where I need the answer which is (A,B,C,D)

Comment: i posted my answer before you edit with the result needed, anyways, good the other solution worked.

Answer (score -2):

If i understood what you said clearly, you can put your result set in an `Array`.
and then use this `SQL QUERY`

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

Example :

```
ALTER TABLE customer ADD name VARCHAR(Max);
```

You can specified a loop from the 0 to size of the Array and put that query inside the loop.

Edit : 
Ok, I think it should be something like this;

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @str = "";

WHILE @cnt < 100000
BEGIN

   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
  SET @str='yourRowName';
ALTER TABLE yourTableName
ADD str datatype
END;
```

Take a look at this.
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/for_loop.php

Comment: Its not even related to SO question..kindly update answer